# Output to New Window in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, output, new-window

How can I get the output of a command (i.e. get-process) to display in a new powershell window with the the -nologo and -noninteractive options. I've tried all sorts of things that don't work like:

```
get-process > start-process powershell.exe -nologo -noninteractive

get-process | write-output start-process powershell.exe -nologo -noninteractive
```

I just can't seem to get my output into a new powershell window, no matter how many ways I Google it. I need to be able to do this when selecting a certain function via my mutli-level powershell menu script.

Comment: shameless bump for some help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
start -FilePath powershell.exe -ArgumentList "-nologo -noninteractive -command {Get-Process}"
```

Will do what you asked for but I have a feeling that may not really be what you want.

Comment: just tried this and it doesn't actually give me the output of the "get-process" command, it just opens a new window with the get-process command at the top and a new prompt (which means -noninteractive isn't working?)

Comment: If you run the command in another console window, you will not get output in the window where you ran it. What exactly do you want to have happen.

Comment: That's exactly what I want EBGreen. I have a menu script that let's me select a number to run different "get-" commands. After running the command, the menu sleeps for x seconds then loops back to the menu. This is a desired function. Some of my "get-" commands have output that takes longer for me to look through, so I would like the output of those commands to be sent to a new powershell window, so i can take my time to review them, while the menu script is allowed to loop back to menu as intended.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output to a new window - Why do you need those options?

This command outputs anything under the command parameter to a new PS Window (sleep timer helps it stay active:

```
Start-process powershell.exe -ArgumentList '-command Write-Host "Explorer Process Current State" -ForegroundColor Red; gps explorer | ft ; Start-Sleep -s 10;'
```